# Redirecionar URL para outra pasta física com .htaccess

Tags: php, apache, ubuntu, htaccess, servidor

No server Ubuntu, tenho uma pasta física:

```
/var/www/html/gestao/site/temp/
```

Gostaria que meu `.htaccess` redirecionasse a URL `domain.com.br/gestao` para esta pasta física de forma transparente.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tive que redirecionar da seguinte forma, infelizmente a URL também muda. Mas resolveu meu problema.

```
RewriteEngine On
Redirect 301 /gestao http://www.domain.com.br/gestao-sys/site/adm/
```

A pasta física **gestao** não existe (que será o digitado na URL). Então será redirecionado para o caminho físico acima.

Answer (score 0):

Veja se isso resolve seu caso!

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^/gestao/site/temp/(.*)$ http://www.seusite.com/gestao/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Nada acontece. Como se estivesse ignorando a regra. Eu sei que o apache está aceitando as regras, pois tenho feito testes e acontece mudanças, mas não o esperado.

Comment: Não seria o contrário, identificando domain.com.br/gestao redireciona para a pasta, como está na pergunta?